# Search a project in SonarQube based on the github Uri

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to search for a project's line coverage using the `SonarQube` `Web API`.

The entrypoint to my search is the github repository uri.

So something like this: `git@github.com:user/my-project.git`.

Currently, I am cutting out the repo name and try to find the project using `/api/projects/index?search=my-project` - assuming that the github repo name should be contained in the sonarqube project name.

I pick up the project key from the response and use it with `/api/measures/component` to retrieve the `overall_line_coverage`.

We are using the SonarQube gradle plugin to create the SonarQube project. We also set the `sonar.branch` property. So we end up with project keys like `<groupId>:<artifactId>:<sonar.branch>`.

Is there a better/more robust way to do this search - especially I would like to add the `sonar.branch` to the query the narrow down the search result.

Comment: Are you using a local installation of sonarqube, or are you analyzing your projects on sonarqube.com?

Comment: We have a local installation. Is there a difference in the API between local and sonarqube.com?

Comment: what is your version of SonarQube?

Comment: We are on SonarQube 6.0

Answer (score 1):

- go to your project homepage to get the project key OR use the internal (made public in 6.3) WS `api/components/search` with the q parameter
- use the WS `api/measures/component` to retrieve your project measure

Comment: Thanks a lot my - totally overlooked that api - since it is marked internal in my version. This search is better than `projects/index` because it lets me search in project keys. Project keys have the form `<groupId>:<artifactId>:<sonar.branch>` for me - so I search for `q=<artifactId>:<sonar.branch>` - e.g. `q=my-project:origin/master` but no match for this one.

Comment: check the project key. Have you explicitly given the sonar.branch=origin/master? Otherwise, there's a good chance the key is solely my-project

Comment: I did - it is `<groupId>:<artifactId>:<sonar.branch>` - e.g. `com.mycompany:my-project:origin/master`